# max sum within a 200mt radius

Tags: r, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I have a SpatialPointData Frame in R. Each point represents lat long and InsuredValue amount. I would like to find the maximum sum of insured value in a radius of 200 mt. How I can do in R

Comment: look into gbuffer() from rgeos and over() from sp. And there are already some examples of what you are asking on SO